# How to implement Leitner algorithm (spaced repetition)?

Tags: algorithm, ios

In the [spaced repetition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaced_repetition) algorithms, we have a particular one named [Leitner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leitner_system). It is used widely for some flashcards based learning systems.  The main idea is to sort up the cards with possibilites.

After searching google, it seems like there are no specific implementations in C, C++, or Object-C except some Ruby implementations.

Question here to seek some clues.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I feel that the following software might be useful for you -- [REDACTED](http://example.com). It's a C++ implementation, and source code is open. You might want to check it out.

EDIT: The URL that was originally provided above, has since been replaced with a phishing scam. Check the comment's history if you truly want to see the link.

Comment: Link has deprecated

Comment: Link is actually gone completely.